# Display umbracoBytes from uploaded file After upgrade to v4.9.1

Tags: umbraco

After recently upgrading a site to v4.9.1  it is no longer filling   umbracoBytes, umbracoExtension label.
[image]

this is my  umbracoSettings.config

```
<imaging>

            <!-- what file extension that should cause umbraco to create thumbnails -->

            <imageFileTypes>jpeg,jpg,gif,bmp,png,tiff,tif</imageFileTypes>

            <!-- what attributes that are allowed in the editor on an img tag -->

            <allowedAttributes>alt,border,class,style,align,id,name,onclick,usemap</allowedAttributes>

            <!-- automatically updates dimension, filesize and extension attributes on upload -->

            <autoFillImageProperties>

                <uploadField alias="umbracoFile">

                    <widthFieldAlias>umbracoWidth</widthFieldAlias>

                    <heightFieldAlias>umbracoHeight</heightFieldAlias>

                    <lengthFieldAlias>umbracoBytes</lengthFieldAlias>

                    <extensionFieldAlias>umbracoExtension</extensionFieldAlias>

                </uploadField>

            </autoFillImageProperties>

        </imaging>
```